# how to bind a `key chord` to more than one `function` in `nano`?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nano

I'm configuring `nano` to make quick edits while using sublime text for working on bigger projects.

I ran into some issues, one of which is not able to bind a single key chord to multiple functions. I tried the following but these don't work:

```
bind M-0  zero               main
bind M-0  linenumbers        main
```

```
bind M-0  zero,linenumbers   main
```

Answer (score 0):

after a day of searching around i finally found the solution (`WildBerry#4098`
from r/unixporn discord server helped me [conversation](https://discord.com/channels/635612648934735892/635625954219261982/1034199551847977100))

```
bind M-0 "{zero}{linenumbers}" main
```

edit: (for future reference) read the nano docs `Rebinding Keys` section (current docs: https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v6/nano.html)